# Points of tangency from a point M to an ellipsoid-plane intersection

Tags: conic-sections, plane-geometry, tangent-line, intersection-theory

Having an spheroid $S$ of semi-major axis $a$ in the equatorial plane in direction $x-axis$ and $y-axis$, and of semi-minor axis $b$ in direction $z-axis$.

$(S): (\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{a})^2+(\frac{z}{b})^2=1$

A plane $(P): ux+vy+wz=d$ intersects $S$
That yields an ellipse $E$ in 3D.

I Intersected $S$ and $P$, I got a quadratic equation of quadratic conics, in the form:
$(E): Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$

After equating and solving, I got the coefficients of the ellipse $E$

$A=(wb)^2+(ua)^2$
$B=2uv(a)^2$
$C=(wb)^2+(va)^2$
$D=-2du(a)^2$
$E=-2dv(a)^2$
$F=a^2(d^2-(bw)^2)$

My question is as follow:

I have a point $M(i,j,k)$ lying in the plane of intersection, and it is outside the ellipse $E$, how to find the coordinates of the two tangent points $B$ and $C$ from the point $M$ to the ellipse $E$?

Please see figure from geogebra:
[image]

**Add**
[image]

Comment: You’ve already reduced this to a two-dimensional problem. Find the points of tangency there and map back to the three-dimensional space. Or, find the intersections of the quadric, the “slicing” plane, and the polar plane to $M$.

Comment: I searched in internet for such problems, not found, that is why I ask here, I left the school since 10 years, I would get  a help, or links helping me, e.g. polar plane, I have already asked similar thing, today otherway asked, I think you were there

Comment: Do you remember that?

Comment: I have an approach in javascript, but it didnt work, should I post it here?

Comment: This is not a site for debugging your code. A description of the mathematics that you’re using in that program would be more appropriate.

Comment: My idea in programming, is to do search binary to find the point $C$ at horizon, I start with a point $Q$, lying on surface, beneath $M$ at the Normal, then I step until the angle between vector $CD$ and $CM$ is equal to 90 degrees, $D$ is at normal of $C$, so above it

Comment: Oy, that is the projection only?!! so should I rotate $E$ to lie on $xyplane$?

Comment: A curve in 3-D space can’t be represented by a single implicit Cartesian equation. Your equation (E) is the equation of an elliptic cylinder parallel to the $z$-axis that happens to have the same intersection with the plane. If you treat (E) as an equation on the $x$-$y$ plane, it represents a *projection* of the ellipse, which will be foreshortened.

Comment: This could be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433025/how-to-find-the-tangent-line-from-a-point-to-an-ellipse/2433224#2433224

Answer (score 1):

Equation of the ellipsoid:

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{b^2}=1 \tag{1}$$

Equation of the polar plane w.r.t. $M$:

$$\frac{ix+jy}{a^2}+\frac{kz}{b^2}=1 \tag{2}$$

Equation of the plane $P$ containing $M$:

$$ux+vy+wz=d \tag{3}$$

under the constraint $ui+vj+wk=d$.

In principle, $(1) \cap (2) \cap (3)$, which is the required intersections, is solvable with discriminant
$$\frac{i^2+j^2}{a^2}+\frac{k^2}{b^2}-1>0$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the equation that you’ve derived ostensibly by solving equation (P) for $z$ and then substituting into (S) isn’t the equation of the intersection curve. Indeed, a curve in a 3-D space can’t be represented by a single implicit Cartesian equation. You’ve got the equation of an elliptical cylinder that happens to have the same intersection with the cutting plane. The intersection of this cylinder with the $x$-$y$ plane is the orthogonal projection of the ellipse, so is in most cases foreshortened.

There are several ways to solve this problem, and the best/easiest really depends on what else you want to know about this configuration. If all you want are the two points of tangency, then a straightforward way to go is to find the intersection of $P$ and the polar plane to $M$, then computing the intersection of this line with the spheroid. If you use a standard parametric representation for the line, this is a straightforward matter of solving a single-variable quadratic equation.

Specifically, the polar plane to $M$ is ${ix\over a^2}+{jy\over a^2}+{kz\over b^2}=1$, so its intersection with $P$ has direction vector $$\mathbf v = \left(\frac i{a^2},\frac j{a^2},\frac k{b^2}\right)\times(u,v,w)$$ and with a bit of work you can find a point on this line, such as $$\mathbf p = \left({dj-a^2v \over ju-iv} , {di-a^2u \over iv-ju}, 0\right).$$ Plug $\mathbf p+t\mathbf v$ into the equation of the spheriod and solve for $t$.

A related approach is to transform the problem into a simpler one that involves intersection with and tangents to the unit sphere, solve that problem, then transform back. The required transformations are simple scaling operations that preserve intersections and tangency. Mapping the spheroid to the unit sphere takes $(i,j,k)$ to $(i/a,j/a,k/b)$ and takes $P$ to the plane $P'$ with equation $aux+avy+bwz=d$. The points of tangency can be found using the method described above, or you could further rotate or reflect to make $P'$ parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane and then solve the simple problem of finding the ends of the chord of contact to a circle. This additional rotation/reflection also makes it fairly easy to compute a parameterization of the intersection curve: it’s just the unit circle rotated/reflected and scaled back into position. Once you have this parameterization of the intersection curve, you can use it to generate test points for the search algorithm that you’ve described.

Finally, there’s a version of the tried-and-true method that you likely learned in planar analytic geometry. Generate a one-parameter family of lines through $M$ that lie in $P$ and work out their intersection with the spheriod. For tangency, you want the resulting equation to have a double root, which will then generate a simple quadratic equation in the line parameter. Once you have that, finding the points of tangency will be a matter of back-substitution.

Comment: Solving for $t$... wolfram gave $t = ((-(2 b^4 j w (d j - a^2 v))/(j u - i v) - (2 b^2 (d i - a^2 u) (a^2 k u - b^2 i w))/(i v - j u) + (2 a^2 b^2 k v (d j - a^2 v))/(j u - i v)) ± sqrt(((2 b^4 j w (d j - a^2 v))/(j u - i v) + (2 b^2 (d i - a^2 u) (a^2 k u - b^2 i w))/(i v - j u) - (2 a^2 b^2 k v (d j - a^2 v))/(j u - i v))^2 - 4 ((b^2 (d j - a^2 v)^2)/(j u - i v)^2 + (b^2 (d i - a^2 u)^2)/(i v - j u)^2 - a^2 b^2) (a^4 b^2 k^2 v^2 - 2 a^2 b^4 j k v w + b^2 (a^2 k u - b^2 i w)^2 + a^2 + b^6 j^2 w^2)))/(2 (a^4 b^2 k^2 v^2 - 2 a^2 b^4 j k v w + b^2 (a^2 k u - b^2 i w)^2 + a^2 + b^6 j^2 w^2))$ So?

Comment: Is that normal that is so long, what would be then when I put these $t$ into the the equation of the line $\mathbf p+t\mathbf v$ to get the coordinates of $B$ and $C$ ?!!

Comment: @Khaled Why would you expect a fully-expanded general solution to be neat and tidy? If I were coding it, I’d do it step by step, with plenty of local variable to hold the intermediate results. Much less likely to introduce an error that way.

Comment: Bcz I would write a code in programming language, for example, a function take parameters then it gives these intersections points

Comment: I didnt find such thing in google

Comment: thank you, I followed your method, I solved for $t$ to get the intersection between the line of intersection of the two planes and the spheroid, it is perfect, but I remarked that when the line passing by $B$ and $C$ is parallel to the $xoy Plane$, that means $C$ is due East to M and at the same time $B$ is due West to M, the solution fails, I got the two roots of $t$ are the same, so it fails to calculate the coordinates of $C$ and of $B$, is there a solution for that :( ?

Comment: @Khaled Assuming that you’ve done everything correctly, a repeated root simply means that there’s only one point of tangency, which will happen when $P$ itself is tangent to the spheroid.

Comment: I know that, but that doesnt happen in my case, bcz the points of tangency lies always on polar plane, and M is never on surface of ellipsoid, just I change the direction of line of sight to a tangent point apart from M

Comment: I ask this question, bcz I would calculate the tangency pts in a wanted direction, e.g. via vincenty formula I got the coordinates of a point in bearing alpha, then I create a plane from M, its projection on surface and this point that I got from vincenty, so I intersect this plane with the polar plane, solve for t and it is perfect, I compared each with geogebra

Comment: So it will never happen a tangent plane to the ellipsoid :)

Comment: I added a figure for illustration, this plane is always perpendicular to the polar plane, so it revolves this line illustrated in image, with this rotation, the points of tangency move just along the horizon

Comment: @Khaled As I said, **IF** you’ve done everything correctly, a repeated root means that the line is tangent to the spheroid. That happens either when $P$ is tangent or $M$ lies on the spheroid. If neither of those is the case, then your implementation of the solution is incorrect.

Comment: I compared my results for all bearing from 0 due North to 360, each 1 degree , all were perfect as with geogebra, just at bearing 90 and 270 ... it fails, if you want I show you my code tomorrow, it is javscript, I change it to a maths bcz here is just math no coding

Comment: One thing more, also in geogebra when the line is parallel to xoy plane, it has no intersection with xoy plane, I think that this the problem, but one difference that geogebra still give the intersection of the line with the spheroid

Comment: When I set the direction for e.g 89.9 instead  of 90 or 269.9 instead of 270 degree direction, it still perfect and correct answers, that makes me fool

Comment: @Khaled So what if the line is parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane? As I wrote in the answer, the point $\mathbf p$ there is an **example** to illustrate the method. It’s quite obviously *not* part of a a general formula since there’s clearly no point on the line with $z=0$ when the line is parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane.